# How do I successfully install sikuly on fedora 16?

Tags: opencv, fedora, sikuli

I have a problem installing sikuli on fedora 16 its a 64 bits architecture, my main problem comes with the compilation of opencv, sikuli requires the 2.1 version of opencv and in the cmake step it tells me it can not find some libraries. I have tried installing the libraries and creating symbolic links but it still will not work, does anybody knows a good tutorial or some good ideas to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to raise a question on Sikuli bug tracker https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli because it's quicker to get the response from developers there.

Here is a question similar to your issue: https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/198796